# C++ Convert Array of Int into one Int

Tags: c++, int

suppose I have this:

```
int ziparr[5];
```

and i've got some elements in it...

```
int ziparr[0] = 2;
int ziparr[1] = 4;
int ziparr[2] = 3;
.....
```

I want to combine them into one int value, for instance

```
int zip = 243
```

What is the best way to concatenate this array into one int value?

Comment: Seems like the simplest would be to loop over the array and convert each number to a string, then simply concatenate each to a master string and at the end convert that back to an int. What if the values are larger than 9, how would you handle that?

Comment: For the purposes of this project, they arent, they're only digits from 0-9

Comment: Your case is slightly simpler than the attached dupe, in that you dont need to consider multi digit numbers. It should be simple to convert without involving strings.  See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZniBYkmGshWZOE6h). It comes with certain caveats though, for instance it could easily overflow and it might not play nice if any of the numbers are negative (outside your stated range but still worth being aware of). To resolve the overflow issue, you can just use a larger type for the `accum` variable.